# Finding tomcat installation directory

Tags: c++, windows, tomcat

I have installed tomcat in my PC (Windows 10). Is there anyway that I can find the installation path of tomcat? I thought of making use of the command line with which java used to call the startup.bat file but then I realized that the command line keeps changing depending on how it is called. I have to find the installation path of tomcat programmatically using c++.

Updated : I need to find the installation path only if tomcat is running

Comment: Your best bet is to find the install path from the registry using Windows API functions.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724895(v=vs.85).aspx may be useful

Comment: Tomcat is just a .bat file not an exe, hence no signs of registry would be there when it is running

Answer (score 0):

You could execute `jps -lv` and parse the results.

A Tomcat Java process would look like

```
12345 org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap ... -Dcatalina.base=<some_path> ...
```

Where `12345` is the PID and `<some_path>` is the home of Tomcat.

Beware that there could be multiple instances of Tomcat running.

Comment: I tried it and its showing the path of my Jdk , not the tomcat directory..